# egrep -i -f whitelist not running

Tags: grep

I am trying to use a file as a whitelist against another file. The whitelist file has email addresses with a \n delimiter. The file is a csv file.

I tried:

```
egrep -i -f whitelist file | tee newfile
```

I also tried:

```
egrep -f whitelist file | tee newfile
```

I also tried:

```
cat file | egrep -i -e -f whitelist | tee newfile
```

When I run these, tee shows no output and the process completes.

```
wc -l *
```

This shows that nothing transferred to the new file.

Please help me! Thank you!

@Etan Reisner:

An example of the whitelist file is:

```
email@email.com
email1@address.com
email2@address.com
```

etc...

An example of the input file is:

```
name,address,email@email.com,...
name,address,email@email.com,...
name,address,email@email.com,...
```

Comment: Show sample contents from the `whitelist` and `file` files.

Comment: not sure what you mean with "whitelist" here. Could you clarify by giving some sample files and desired output?

Comment: I am trying to use a  file that has email addresses listed per line with a \n delimiter to filter against a csv file. Each row of the csv file has data such as name, email, etc. I want only the rows of the csv file that contain an email address in the "whitelist" to print to the output file.

Comment: I just added examples of whitelist and input file to my question.

Comment: The whitelist and input may have 20,000 -1,000,000 lines. I need this for more than one file. Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui the output file needs to preserve the data in each filtered row. Each row: first,last,address,email